# In MVC 4 assign client side DropDown value to Model Property on Submit

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have 1 Client side drop down in the view. Content for Dropdowns is loaded from Js file.
On submit I want the selected dropdown value to be assigned to Model property and send it to Controller.

Model

```
public class TestMe
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit (TestMe viewModel)
{
 ....
}
```

View

```
<select name="Id">
    <option value="0">High</option>
    <option value="1">Medium</option>
    <option value="2">Low</option>
</select>
```

MVC 4  , Razor , C#.Net Visual Studio 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your model and view code.

Comment: I just saw your post. I will copy your sample to me question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why don't generate this Dropdown by Html Helpers ??**

Anyway just make sure that your Client side drop down is in the form tag and make it's name just as your Model property name and everything should work.

I suppose that you've something like this.

```
public class TestMe{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

and your drop down represent the Id property and your controller action is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit (TestMe viewModel)
{
....
}
```

**Then your drop down should has name attribute with "Id" value.**

```
<select name="Id" id="Id">
<option value="10">10</option>
.......
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry Wahid, Always first option is being passed to controller

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell you to add Id attribute. Anyway just make sure it's in the form tag